# How can i use urlrewrite to serve up different content to different users?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am making a quiz and I need to serve up different content to different countries that may access it.

Currently the method I am using is just duplicating the content and placing it in a different directory. For example the brazil version of the quiz is called index.php and it sits in

```
www.example.com/br/index.php
```

Since there are several of these quizzes it is difficult to make changes because if I change one thing I have to go in and change each one by hand. I have been instructed to use urlrewrite to make the modification process simpler but I have no idea how this works.

So how can I use urlrewrite to serve up different content for the different countries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely *not* recommend that you do this in rewrite rules, but, rather, that you do it in the index.php itself, where it will be much more efficient, and likely tons easier.

Consider using the GeoIP package in php - http://php.net/manual/en/book.geoip.php - or MaxMind - https://github.com/maxmind/- which does all of this logic for you. Or, simpler (but less accurate) do a reverse lookup on their IP address and skim off the country code from the result.

Comment: I really appreciate your response. 

This method was suggested by my coworker and he seemed shocked that I didn't know how to use this method.

I am going to try and use yours as it makes much more sense to me.

Comment: I'd be quite curious to see what rewrite techniques your coworker suggested. But I'm reasonably certain that doing it in actual program code will be tens, possibly even hundreds of times faster.